# CnosDB-cli exec "ALTER DATABASE database SET REPLICA 4" encountered problems

Tags: cnosdb

Step1：

```
cp config_8912.toml config_8922.toml
cp config_8912.toml config_8932.toml
```

Step2：

vim config_8922.toml config_8932.toml

```
[storage]
    path = '/tmp/cnosdb/4001/db'
    
[wal]
  path = '/tmp/cnosdb/4001/wal'
[log]
  path = '/tmp/cnosdb/4001/log'
[cluster]
  http_listen_port = 8932
  grpc_listen_port = 8933
  flight_rpc_listen_port = 8934
  tcp_listen_port = 8935
[node_basic]
  node_id = 4001
[hinted_off]
  enable = true
  path = '/tmp/cnosdb/4001/hh'
```

Step3：

```
create database oceanic_station;
```

Step4：

```
CREATE TABLE air (
  visibility DOUBLE,
  temperature DOUBLE,
  pressure DOUBLE,
  TAGS(station)
);
```

Step5：

```
ALTER DATABASE oceanic_station SET REPLICA 4;
```

Step6：

```
DESCRIBE DATABASE oceanic_station;
+----------+-------+----------------+------------------+---------+-----------+
| TTL      | SHARD | VNODE_DURATION | COOLING_DURATION | REPLICA | PRECISION |
+----------+-------+----------------+------------------+---------+-----------+
| 365 Days | 1     | 365 Days       | 0 Days           | 4       | NS        |
+----------+-------+----------------+------------------+---------+-----------+
```

Step7：

```
CREATE TABLE wind (
  visibility DOUBLE,
  temperature DOUBLE,
  pressure DOUBLE,
  TAGS(station)
);
```

Step8：
cd /tmp/cnosdb/x001/

**Only one node has data**

Then, I tried to do this:

Step3：

```
drop database oceanic_station;
```

Step4：

```
create database oceanic_station;
```

Step4：

```
ALTER DATABASE oceanic_station SET REPLICA 4;

CREATE TABLE air (
  visibility DOUBLE,
  temperature DOUBLE,
  pressure DOUBLE,
  TAGS(station)
);
```

......

After performing this operation, check that the data under /tmp/cnosdb/x001/ is evenly distributed.
So the function of ALTER DATABASE database SET REPLICA 4 is not so useful?